# Main app cannot find a pod used by custom shared framework

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, realm, xcframework

I have a main app "authenticator" that uses a custom framework "storage". The "storage" use RealmSwift to handle any CRUD functionality and being used by the main app and its embedded extensions. This is the Podfile:

```
# Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

workspace 'authenticator-ios'

target 'authenticator-ios' do
  project 'authenticator-ios'
  # Pods for authenticator-ios
  pod 'Rudder', '~> 1.15.1'
  pod 'RxSwift', '6.6.0'
  pod 'RxCocoa', '6.6.0'
  pod 'KeychainAccess'
  pod 'Swinject'
  pod 'SwiftOTP', :git => 'https://github.com/lachlanbell/SwiftOTP.git', :branch => 'swift-5.0-cryptoswift'
  pod 'RecaptchaEnterprise', '18.3.0'
  pod 'RealmSwift', '~>10'
  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'RxAlamofire'
  pod 'SwiftLint'
  pod 'lottie-ios'
  
  target 'authenticator-iosTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
    pod 'RxBlocking', '6.6.0'
    pod 'RxTest', '6.6.0'
  end

  target 'authenticator-iosUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
    pod 'RxBlocking', '6.6.0'
    pod 'RxTest', '6.6.0'
  end
end

target 'storage' do
  project 'storage'
  pod 'RealmSwift', '~>10'
  target 'storageTests' do
  end
end


# FORCE SET DEPLOYMENT TARGET TO 11.0 SINCE platform :ios, '11.0' DIDN'T DO ANYTHING!
post_install do |pi|
    pi.pods_project.targets.each do |t|
        t.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
        end
    end
end
```

I have done `pod install`. I have added the `storage.framework` into the `Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content` in `General` tab and `Link Binary With Libraries` in `Build Phases` tab. When I switch the scheme to `storage`, I can build the framework. But when I switch back and try to build the main app it returned this error:

`No such module 'RealmSwift'`

And the corresponding line is not a line from the `main app`'s classes, but the `storage` framework's. It is in all of the derivations of `RealmSwift.Object` that are only used internally in the framework. The main app shouldn't (and doesn't) know about these classes.

Case in point: [image: Error]

Can anybody tell me what's wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Is RealmSwift built for *storagetests*?

Comment: @jay I still don't have any test in the extension. So I don't think so.

Comment: It appears the file containing TransactionObject is not aware of Realm. Can you temporarily move that object to another file - perhaps in the `authenticator-ios` file just to see if it makes a difference?

Comment: It works on the main target / `authenticator-ios`. The class was prior to me extracting it to the `storage` framework. That's why I'm confused.